# Geometry Nodes: Constrain instances on faces to the bounds of each face

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, instances

I'd like to instance a vaguely square-shaped object onto each face of an input mesh. I can rotate the instances to fit the face normals and scale them to fit the face area, but I'd like each instance to deform to the 4 corners of whatever face they're instancing on. Is there a way to do this?

[image]

In this image you can see the 4 corners of the instance object, and the bounds of faces I'd like those to align to. My working theory is there may be a way to output a UVMap attribute per face, then transfer that attribute to the instances.

Comment: Yes, of course there is a possibility. However, I would not recommend this procedure. If you subsequently adapt such a geometry to any other object, this always results in a distortion of the geometry. Is that what you want? Maybe you can share your blend file so that we can get a better picture and help you to achieve your goal in a different way.

Comment: Not a real answer, but the ideal solution is coming soon in the form of the Tesselate node https://developer.blender.org/D13515